# What do you call someone who is easy to relate to?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call someone who is easy to relate to?
For example, someone who has been through something you have been through, like similar life experiences.

Comment: or, maybe we can say, 'soul-mate'? :)

Comment: Please can you give us a few example sentences where you would use this word? More context will make it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 7):

Do you mean someone with whom you have good camaraderie? Someone whom you find it especially easy to relate to; Or are you describing someone who is generally an all-round popular guy, who makes friends easy, and is easy to be friends with?

If it is someone whom you personally can relate to, you could try **"Kindred spirit"**

If it's someone who can easily relate to everyone, you could try "Sociable?" "Outgoing?"

Comment: Kindred spirit is good. What about fellow traveler? Or maybe soul sister / soul brother?

Answer (score 3):

Someone who is easy to relate to could be a *relatable* or *personable* person.

Answer (score 1):

[Gregarious](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=define%3agregarious&hl=en) perhaps?

> gre·gar·i·ous   fond of the company of others; sociable.